# Accessing XML nodes to use as image URL with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```xml
<photos> <!-- this is the ROOT element -->

<User id='200901544'>~/images/image1.jpg</User>
<User id='200901566'>~/images/image7.jpg</User>

</photos>
```

First, I want to access the `User` element to get the image URL of the `User` with the `id` attribute `200901544`. I would then like to tie that URL to an image button.

**Here's my problem:** I also want to compare the `id` attribute to a string (which is the id) from the user to check if it's valid. The `id` is for displaying a photo in a web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ2XML

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");   
string dp=doc.Elements("User").Where(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value==yourAttribute).Select(y=>y.Value).First();
```

`yourAttribute` is the attribute you want to compare